# execute timer when right after started?

Tags: c#, timer

I have a timer with interval 3600000 which can be translated into an hour, so when I do

```
timer.Start()
```

it will it will execute code below in every hour starting from next hour

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    .....
}
```

but what if I want it to be also executed the second I call timer.Start() and then every hour after?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The simplest option would be to just call the method:

```
timer.Start();
timer_Tick(null, EventArgs.Empty); // Simulate a timer tick event
```

This doesn't actually trigger the timer, but calls your handler immediately, effectively simulating a "now" event.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand `System.Threading.Timer` does exactly what you want.

It allows you to specify when the first invocation must occur and then the interval between invocations.

So if you set the first invocation to 0 milliseconds and the interval to an hour, it will fire immediately and then every hour.

> dueTime 
>   Type: System.Int32 The amount of time to delay before callback
>   is invoked, in milliseconds. Specify Timeout.Infinite to prevent the
>   timer from starting. Specify zero (0) to start the timer immediately.
>
> period Type: System.Int32 The time interval between invocations of
>   callback, in milliseconds. Specify Timeout.Infinite to disable
>   periodic signaling.

Answer (score 0):

Simply I would do right after you call Start(), call the function manually.